# Create a View From a Table not authorized Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I am just following a very simple microsoft tutorial, at the topic **Create a View From a Table**:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hh272116

I created the view called **TITO_SomeView** .
I used the **DirAddressBookParty** table, I can't open the view and I am getting the message:

**"You are not authorized to access table ‘Some view’ (TITO_SomeView). Contact your system administrator."**

Comment: maybe you forget to add fields on the view, just click the fields datasource, look off the dynamics property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would it be that you have not assigned any fields under the "Fields".

After **Save** and **Compile**, then you can open it.

Answer (score 1):

After we have completed Upgrade from AX 2009 to AX 2012, when we try to open some tables that have PriceDisc Configuration Key it prompts an error "You are not authorized to access table ‘Price disc sales policy parameters' "

That happens because the Configuration Key (PriceDisc) was disabled during the upgrade.

The solution is to re-enable it from : `Administration > Setup > System > License Configuration`

Then it will synchronize related tables. Try again to open the form / table in this case it's `Price disc sales policy parameters`.